# Column name as a parameter which is obtained from a jtextfield in INSERT statement in java

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Iam using Jpanel in which when I enter a textfield values say c1 and c2 .
These values are stored in row[0] and row[1] and  should be passed as a column name and value in my sql syntax.

I'am writing something like this:

```
 String queryco = "Insert into table(?) values (?)";
 pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);

    String c1 = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 0);
    String c2 = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 1);

        pst.setString(1, c1);
        pst.setString(2, c2);

        pst.addBatch();
```

I'am just a beginner and not sure if this will work.
how else can i write the INSERT syntax?

Comment: nice question, what is the problem with this?

Comment: values are not getting stored in database